# Open Form with Request-Product-Button

Tags: roomle

we would like to open a modal with a form when the user clicks the request-product-button. We want to send the configuration with the form.

How do we get the values into the form and how to open a modal on click?

Regards

Answer (score 2):

Here is the documentation on how to listen to `onRequestProduct`: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#listen-to-onrequestproduct

In the callback you get configurationId, image, partlist, price, labels and configuration. Depending on what you need you can then open your modal and pass them as values.

Comment: Ok, thanks. But where do I have to place the script?
We use the iframe integration in our website.

Thanks!

Comment: You need to use the embedding lib instead of the iframe integration to communicate with the configurator. Here are the docs to get you started: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#getting-started

Comment: Which parameters can I use in the iframe-url? Is it possible to attach email to the url?

Comment: Which email do you want to attach, what are you trying to achieve? You can find a full list of parameters here: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/api/interfaces/uiinitdata.html#properties

Comment: not API. I wanted to know if it is possible to send a mail with the request button which is used in the iframe.

Comment: @daenzo you can react to the event which is triggered when a user clicks the request-button. How this is done, is described here: https://docs.roomle.com/web/embedding/#listen-to-onrequestproduct Then you can implement your own logic around the on-request-event. This could be of course sending it via e-mail. But this happens then in the code of the webshop and not inside of Roomle Rubens. I hope this clarifies things :-)

Comment: you are talking about the API. I wanted to know what I can do with the request button when the configurator is implemented with the iframe?

Comment: If you only use the iframe integration the request button does not have any function.

Comment: but why is there a button if it has no function?

Comment: If you use the embedding API you can define which function it should have. But we should probably hide it if you are just using the iFrame.